# Переход на Discord.py 2.0

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, update

В общем, писала бота +- на discord.py 1.7.3 или что то вроде, недавно отказали эти библиотеки и пришлось обновляться. Как итог полный отказ работы бота. Узнала про изменения когов и тп, щас бот запускается, некоторые команды даже работают, меняется статус... Но по большей части команды все же не работают, мне не понятно почему, ибо ни слова нету в терминале. Как будто ошибок нет. Что нужно поменять чтобы это прекратилось? xd

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь в правильности установки библиотеки, самую свежую версию можно установить командой из официального репозитория разработчика. Для данного способа необходим [Git](https://git-scm.com/):

```
python -m pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
```

Полный список изменений в discord.py 2.0 можно посмотреть [здесь](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html).

Comment: Обновление привело к тому, что поменялось много всего в api, ну так вот я про то< что нужно поменять на что, чтобы заработал код. Например member.avatar_url в member.avatar щас надо делать

Comment: Я дал ссылку на полный список того, что нужно поменять.